# How can we find the least perfect square number divisible by each one of 3, 4, 5, 6,8 with easy 1 min solution?

Tags: least-squares, square-numbers

If we find the **LCM of these numbers we get** **120** but thats not the answer and after that I'm not able to do anything further, can anybody help me?

Comment: Use prime factorization

Comment: Has to have the form $2^a3^b5^c$ so...

Comment: 3, 2*2,5,3*2, so answer will be 3*3*2*2*5*5=900

Comment: prime factorization of what? 120? whats the logic behind it?

Comment: Primes in $3,4,5,6$ is the logic. If $p\mid n^2$, then also $p\mid n$.

Comment: Note:  the least common multiple of those numbers is $60$.

Comment: people I corrected the typo, the correct numbers are 3,4,5,6,8
and I'll give a hint, the answer in the options is 3600

Comment: The logic is the same.  It's still $2^a3^b5^c$.

Comment: @lulu could you please implement this logic into an explanatory answer, I'll be thankful

Comment: The posted solution from @DietrichBurde follows this logic.

Answer (score 2):

For the corrected version of the problem:

The number must be divisible by $120=2^3\times3\times5$. It is a perfect square. So it is at least $2^4\times3^2\times 5^2$.

Comment: I corrected a typo, the numbers are 3,4,5,6,8

Comment: Please explain your method in words, I'll be thankful

Comment: $120$ is the LCM. The number must be a multiple of it.  As the number is a perfect square, it must be a product of even powers of primes. $4$ is the smallest even number $\ge 3$ and $2$ is the smallest even number $\ge 1$.

Answer (score 0):

For $p\mid n^2$ and $p$ prime it follows that $p\mid n$. Since $2,3,5$ are the primes in $3,4,5,6$, we need at least $2,3,5$ as divisors for $n$. So $n=30$ and $n^2=900$ is the minimal choice. If you add $8$, then $p=2$ has to appear with multiplicity $3$ in $n^2$, so at least with multiplicty $2$ in $n$. Hence $n=2\cdot 30$ is minimal, which means $n^2=3600$.

Comment: numbers are 3,4,5,6,8 and the option that is the answer is 3600

Comment: You mean, "new" answer is $3600$. Old answer is $900$.

Comment: What is the symbol |

Comment: $p\mid n$ denotes "$p$ divides $n$", see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor).

Comment: Thanks professor

Answer (score 0):

We can actually disregard $6$ and $8$, because we're already demanding that $n^2$ be divisible by $3$ and by $4$. So once we find our $n$, we'll see that it's also divisible by $9$ and by $16$.

So the least common multiple of $3$, $4$ and $5$ is $60$. This means the answer is $60^2 = 3600$.

Now, $900$ won't do because it is divisible by $4$ but not by $8$.